# Difference between current time and future time in java

Tags: java, time, timer, timertask, difference

I am using Java Timer class for running certain task. For my program I will give starttime and endtime as parameters which will ask the java timer when to start and when to end the task.

While running my task, I want to get and check the difference between current time and endtime periodically and If current time equals endtime then cancel the task by calling `timer.cancel()` method.

My `startTime` and `endTime` parrameters time format are like this

```
String startTime = "12:00";
String endTime = "12:01";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
Date date1 = format.parse(startTime);
Date date2 = format.parse(endTime);
long difference = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
```

I want to check the current time is equal to endtime.

But I want to check the condition that the current time is equal to end time and call the `timer.cancel()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be, you just don't know how to get the *endTime*.

```
String startTime = "12:00";

SimpleDateFormat sDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "hh:mm");
String endTime = sDateFormat.format(new java.util.Date());

if (startTime.equals(endTime)) {
    timer.cancel();
}
```

try, and good luck

Comment: Don't worry, it's simple. Change the line 2:                            `SimpleDateFormat sDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "hh:mm");`                                                                                          to                                                                                           `SimpleDateFormat sDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "HH:mm");`

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the time problem..

If comparing two Strings, you'd better use `equals()`

Try this :

```
if(currentTime.equals(endTime)) {
    timer.cancel();
}
```

Comment: I am not concerned about the condition. I need to find the the current time is equal to endtime or not

Comment: Actually, I don't get it..
Is the currentTime given from other class or do you have to get it? And what about the endTime?
If you only have the endTime given, then use System.currentTimeMillis() to get currentTime in long type and compare with the given endTime.

Comment: When I compare with `System.currentTimeMillis()` with endTime in milliseconds, the `if` condition is not triggering

Comment: Try if ( System.currentTimeMillis() >= endTime){} Maybe currentTimeMillis() skips the exact endTime.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the "currentTime.equals(endTime)" function to compare strings, not the == operator.The ".equals" function checks the actual contents of the string, the == operator checks whether the references of both the objects are equal which is not valid in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check if the current time is equal to the end time - that is understood but to what level do you wish to check if it is equal - up to the minute, second or millisecond? Since if you compare by the millisecond or lower it is possible that you may never cancel even when the time may be same to the second.

If you want to check to the millisecond - just convert your end date to millis date.getTime() and subtract System.currentTimeMillis() - if the result is 0 it is same to the millisecond. If the difference is less than 1000 (1 * 1000) it is within the second. If it is less than 60000 (1 * 60 * 1000) it is within the minute.